# Python download image from HTTPS aspx

Tags: python, asp.net, https, python-requests, binaryfiles

I am trying to download some images from NASS Case Viewer. An example of a case is

- https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=149006692

The link to the **image viewer** for this case is

- https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?ImageView&ImageID=497001669&Desc=FRONT&Title=Vehicle+1+-+Front&Version=1&Extend=jpg

which may not be viewable, I assume because of the https. However, this is simply the **Front** second image.

The actual link to the image is (or should be?)

- https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?Image&ImageID=497001669&CaseID=149006692&Version=1

This will simply download aspx binaries.

My problem is that I do not know how to store these binaries to proper jpg files.

Example of code I've tried is

```
import requests 
test_image = "https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?Image&amp;ImageID=497001669&amp;CaseID=149006692&amp;Version=1"
pull_image = requests.get(test_image)

with open("test_image.jpg", "wb+") as myfile:
    myfile.write(str.encode(pull_image.text))
```

But this does not result in a proper jpg file. I've also inspected `pull_image.raw.read()` and saw that it's empty.

What could be the issue here? Are my URL's improper? I've used Beautifulsoup to put these URLs together and reviewed them by inspecting the HTML code from a few pages.

Am I saving the binaries incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text` decodes the response content to string, so  your imge file will be corrupted.
Instead you should use [`.content`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) which holds the binary response content.

```
import requests 

test_image = "https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?Image&amp;ImageID=497001669&amp;CaseID=149006692&amp;Version=1"
pull_image = requests.get(test_image)

with open("test_image.jpg", "wb+") as myfile:
    myfile.write(pull_image.content)
```

`.raw.read()` also returns bytes, but in order to use it you must set the `stream` parameter to `True`.

```
pull_image = requests.get(test_image, stream=True)
with open("test_image.jpg", "wb+") as myfile:
    myfile.write(pull_image.raw.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to follow up on @t.m.adam 's answer to provide a complete answer for anyone who is interested in using this data for their own projects.

Here is my code to pull all images for a sample of Case IDs. It's fairly un-clean code, but I think it gives you what you may need to get started.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tqdm import tqdm


CaseIDs = [149006673, 149006651, 149006672, 149006673, 149006692, 149006693]

url_part1 = 'https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/'

data = []
with requests.Session() as sesh:
    for caseid in tqdm(CaseIDs):
        url_full = f"https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?ViewText&CaseID={caseid}&xsl=textonly.xsl&websrc=true"
        #print(url_full)
        source = sesh.get(url_full).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        tr_tags = soup.find_all('tr',  style="page-break-after: always")
        for tag in tr_tags:
            #print(tag)
            """
            try:
                vehicle = [x for x  in tag.text.split('\n') if 'Vehicle' in x][0] ## return the first element
            except IndexError:
                vehicle = [x for x  in tag.text.split('\n') if 'Scene' in x][0] ## return the first element
            """
            tag_list = tag.find_all('tr', class_ = 'label')
            test = [x.find('td').text for x in tag_list]
            #print(test)
            img_id, img_type, part_name = test
            img_id = img_id.replace(":", "")
            img = tag.find('img')
            #part_name = img.get('alt').replace(":", "").replace("/", "")
            part_name = part_name.replace(":", "").replace("/", "")
            image_name = " ".join([img_type, part_name, img_id]) + ".jpg"
            url_src = img.get('src')
            img_url =  url_part1 + url_src
            print(img_url)
            pull_image = sesh.get(img_url, stream=True)
            with open(image_name, "wb+") as myfile:
                myfile.write(pull_image.content)
```